# Affine geometry textbook

Tags: mathematical-physics, book-recommendation, affine-geometry

What's a good recommendation for a book on affine geometry at the undergrad level?  I ask because I skimmed through the first bit of Vladimir Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* and saw that he talks about Euclidean space in the context of affine geometry -- which I've never studied.  If the book also included a section on symplectic geometry, that'd be a plus, but not mandatory.